# Java - Pausing Akka Scheduler

Tags: java, akka

So I have this scheduler, which is not doing anything right now except incrementing a number . When it gets to 5, I want to pause it and afterwards reset the number `tries`. I get to the point where `totalTries` reached 5, and then it stops for 30 seconds. But after those 30 seconds have passed, it instantly logs the next 5 `totalTries` and pauses again. Clearly, something more is going on behind the curtains.

Am I misunderstanding how this is used? What I want to do is pause the ActorSystem `system` entirely for that period of time. Any hints greatly appreciated.

```
system.scheduler().schedule(
    Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    new Runnable() {            

        public void run() { 

                int totalTries = incrementTries(1);
                logger.info("tries: " + totalTries);

                if(totalTries >= 5) {
                    logger.info("5 tries reached, waiting 30 seconds.");                                
                    try {               
                        Thread.sleep(30000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        logger.info("Sleep interrupted" + e);
                    }
                    resetTries();
                }                           
            }
        }
    }, system.dispatcher());
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pause the ActorSystem as far as I know. What your code does by calling Thread.sleep(30000) is blocking the scheduler thread, when it wakes up, it tries to catch up on its schedule by issuing pending notifications - that's correct behaviour.

Using Thread.sleep to block a thread in an actor system is not recommended.

What I'd do is:

Once your counter reaches 5:

- cancel the schedule
- schedule a new one-off notification in 30 seconds with a handler that will schedule the original notification all over again

Alternatively, you can keep the original schedule going and once your counter reaches 5:

- set a flag to ignore further notifications
- schedule a new one-off notification in 30 seconds with a handler that will unset the flag set in the above step